# Is there a way to turn off the camera 'wobble' on attack?

Tags: dead-island

I've already altered the FOV in Dead Island, but I'm noticing that the constant "wobble" of the screen when making attacks is getting a bit disorienting and distracting. I'm OK with the camera shaking and such when not-so-common events happen (even getting knocked down is fine), but the constant back and forth of the camera while swinging weapons is getting to me.

Any way to turn this off or reduce the effect?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any default or good ways to fix this,however someone made the fix for this and uploaded it to one of the file hosting sites but as it goes with them it is removed at this point.Someone else started a conversation about how he made the fix and this is what he had.

"Place varlist_dof.scr in the my documents\dead island\out\data\scripts folder and change the dof values to a lower number or zero."

Default file:

VarFloat("f_dof_strength_factor", 0.0)

VarFloat("f_dof_near_strength", 0.0)

VarFloat("f_dof_near_offset", 0.0)

VarFloat("f_dof_near_range", 900.0)

VarFloat("f_dof_distance", 1000.0)

VarFloat("f_dof_far_offset", 0.0)

VarFloat("f_dof_far_range", 18000.0)

VarFloat("f_dof_far_strength", 1.0)

There are rumors that in newer versions of the game this won't work,there are chances they fixed it since many people complained on this.I would try and confirm this but I don't have dead island currently.

Comment: Wow, kudos for an answer on an old question. I might have to replay this as one of the characters I didn't do with this fix.